# AWS Redshift Cursor's fails with: DECLARE CURSOR may only be used in transaction blocks;

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, datagrip, database-cursor

First, I understand cursors are not performant but I need one in my specific case.

In AWS Redshift I have the following code:

```
BEGIN;
  DECLARE newCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM DBFoo.TableBar;
  FETCH NEXT FROM newCursor;
  CLOSE newCursor;
```

I get the following error:

> Amazon Invalid operation: DECLARE CURSOR may only be used in transaction blocks;

Since "BEGIN;" directly precedes "DECLARE newCursor CURSOR" I don't understand why it is failing, or how to get it to work

edit: I am connecting to Redshift via Datagrip. This is a brand new session. If I declare the cursor before the BEGIN is also failed because it requires a transaction block

Comment: Have you committed or rolled back any prior transaction? Does this happen if you declare the cursor as the very first thing that you do in a session? For that matter, how are you connecting to Redshift (`psql`, programmatic, or some tool?).

Comment: I am connecting to Redshift via Datagrip. This is a brand new session. If I declare the cursor before the BEGIN is also failed because it requires a transaction block

Answer (score 2):

Your session is likely in "autocommit" mode.  This basically means that every ';' is an implied COMMIT.  You can confirm this by looking at svl_statementtext for your session and seeing if the xid of your statements keeps changing even after issuing a BEGIN.  If this is the cause you will need to refer to Datagrip documentation to determine how turn autocommit off.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it was set to auto commit. When I changed it to manual commit it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

[DataGrip documentation about transaction mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/query-console.html#input_icons) and [execution behavior](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/run-a-query.html#configuring-execution).

Also, you can change it from console toolbar per console/session

[image: Tx:mode]

and set it per data source

[image: Tx:mode for data source]